# Anime where heroes are sent to the past after the dragon they killed explodes

Tags: story-identification, anime

I can't seem to remember the name of this anime but I can describe it.

Five or six heroes defeat a dragon. The protagonist can rewrite/destroy magic symbols but has been often overlooked in general. His powers are finally acknowledged by his team at the end by his team. As they discuss what they gonna do next, the dragon's dead body explodes and they don't have anything left to survive it. But instead of dying the protagonist finds himself in the past.

He sees friends that have lost their lives and realizes he is in the past. One of his best friends - a girl with wind power is there. Also a buy with blue hair and a master of the rapier. They don't know him but he knows them.

The story continues with how he now uses his future knowledge of what happens to save the friends that would have died. He meets the other hero party members also.

I really cant seem to recollect the name of this anime. Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[A Returner's Magic Should Be Special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Returner%27s_Magic_Should_Be_Special)*

[image: Front cover of A Returner's Magic Should Be Special]

> Ten years ago, the world became a Shadow World that resulted in the death of the majority of the world's inhabitants. To save the world, 150 million mages entered the Shadow Labyrinth to clear it, but only six remain. The remaining mages finally defeat the dungeon boss Boromir Napolitan. After the battle, the six reflect on their adventure. However, the dragon's heart suddenly explodes, releasing the tremendous amount of mana it stored to destroy the world and kill the remaining mages. One of the last six, Desir Herrman, finds himself returning 13 years into the past right before the Hebrion Academy entrance ceremony. Brigitte, a professor at the school, explains the entrance exam and its objective, to clear a pseudo-Shadow World. In the school's courtyard, Desir is approached by his mentor, the second-year student and fire mage Ladoria Doriche, who brings him to the test area. Desir explains that Hebrion Academy has a discriminatory practice of putting all nobles in the alpha class and commoners in the beta class regardless of their test results, and those in the beta class are not properly educated. After passing by Elheim Trikincy, a second-year alpha class student who Ladoria despises, and being ridiculed by him, Desir arrives at the test area where he meets Romantica Eru, a comrade who died in the previous timeline.

Found with a search for `anime rebirth dragon explodes`

### Trailer

Romantica Eru would be the wind mage. Pram Schneider is the swordsman.